# Missing CsrfTokenRequestHandler when importing Spring Security Test 5.8.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-test

I'm writing unit test to test my secured endpoint (with `@PreAutorized annotation`), like described in [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/test.html#testing-bearer-authentication). But when the test arrive to the

```java
.with(jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_data.read"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_openid"))))
```

instruction the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfTokenRequestHandler` exception is raise.

In my project I've imported

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>5.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

but I've excluded

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.15</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

I'm expecting to have the class, has described here in the [javadoc.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfTokenRequestHandler.html)

This is not the only missing class/method. Indeed I miss also XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler and others.

**My pom.xml**
This is my resource server pom.xml. All the versions are managed inside the  tag in the parent project (I write here has a comment).

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent.myparent</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
    
<groupId>com.test.vehicle.resource</groupId>
<artifactId>vehicle-res-server</artifactId>
<name>vehicle-res-server</name>
<description>Vehicle resource server</description>
    
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<!--    <springboot.version>2.7.15</springboot.version>-->
</properties>
    
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.parent.myparent</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OpenAPI  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
    </dependency>
            
    <!-- JDBC Connectors -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
<!--        <version>12.2.0.jre8</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<!--        <version>${springboot.version}</version>-->
      </dependency>
        
    <!-- TEST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<!--        <version>5.8.6</version>-->
<!--        Now I set it to 5.7.10 to avoid the error-->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.parent.myparent</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Code snippet**

This is my unit test. I'll never arrive at the andDo instruction.

```java
this.mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .get("/vehicle/all")
                    .with(jwt().authorities(
                            new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_data.read"), 
                            new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_openid"))))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

I find out that if I don't remove the parent dependency my unit test run without problem.

**QUESTION**

So, I'm wondering why I need to have the parent to successfully run the unit test. Is it possible to perform this strategy without the parent? Or do I have to find another way (I've already find it but it is less compact and elegant)?

Comment: Why have you excluded the parent? The parent is there to declare versions for all spring dependencies so that you have the right combinations of versions that work together for version 2.7.15

Comment: @Toerktumlare I exclude the parent because I don't need it. I have a child project and a parent one. In the parent's pom I set a list of dependencies under the _<dependencyManagement>_ tag. I have found another way to permorm my unit test, my question is why if I exclude the parent the **CsrfTokenRequestHandler** is not imported. Is it due to any particular reason and the only way to perform the unit test in the way that I explaind in the question is to have the parent in my pom? If it is true, then why?

Comment: it is impossible to answer unless we see your entire pom.xml structure. The parent declares what versions are used, and if you remove it said version might not be set. I recommend you run a `mvn dependency:tree` on your project and check what is resolved.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I found out that I'm importing _spring-security-web 5.7.10_ in my project with _spring-boot-starter-security 2.7.15_. I also import _spring-security-test 5.8.6_, but the _spring-security-web 5.8.6_ inside it is omitted. This will cause the error for the missing _CsrfTokenRequestHandler_. So, why is this error raise? In fact inside spring-security-web 5.7.10 there isn't this class. One other observation: if I change version for spring-security-test to 2.7.10 all my unit tests are ok (also the one that gave me problem). So, why is this happening (In 2.7.10 there isn't the class)?

Comment: For my first question: could this error be raise for some kind of conflict between the the versions, also if the 5.8.6 is omitted? If true, why this is happening?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I also modified the question and I insert my pom.xml

Comment: Why do you have the api-common both as a parent and as a dependency?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I don't know if it is a bad choise, but I have also some common classes, for my resource server projects, in my parent project. So I need to import them. But, instead, have you any clue of what could be the problem that raise the error?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe you have included enough information nor created a minimal sample, so I'm unable to determine what dependencies are on your classpath. But based on your error, you are likely mixing Spring Security 5.7 (managed by Spring Boot 2.7) and Spring Security 5.8. You should only have Spring Security 5.8 on your classpath.

Please see the [Spring Boot with Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/getting-spring-security.html#getting-maven-boot) section of [Getting Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/getting-spring-security.html) in the 5.8 version of the docs for instructions on how to get 5.8 on your classpath.

Comment: Ok, probably this is the cause of the problem. But why, if under the Dependecy Hierarchy of SpringToolSuite4 the 5.8.6 version of spring-security-web is omitted for conflict with the 5.7.10 version, is the error raise? I mean, I don't import the 5.8.6 right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to that, or I may not understand the question. To remove IDE issues, try running your build using the command line instead.